# Rails app has parent & child ids wrong way round in route helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, helper

I have an Rails app with a parent object Mom and child object Kid. The scaffolds were as far as possible generated rather than hand-coded. In `/app/views/kids/_kid.html.erb` I added

```
<%= mom_kid_path(kid) %>
```

For a Mom with id **1** and a Kid with id **2** this is showing `/moms/2/kids/1`, which has the ids the wrong way round.

All I have in `/config/routes.rb` is

```
resources :moms do
  resources :kids
end
```

What did I do wrong?

The code for the app is at https://github.com/dominicsayers/momkid. The exact steps I took to create the app are here: https://www.dominicsayers.com/howto-create-a-simple-parent-child-form-in-rails-3-1/. I'm happy to add any other specific information that is requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT/ANSWER:

Rails needs both the mom and kid variable when using the _path helper. So it should look more like this:

```
<%= mom_kid_path(kid.mom, kid) %>
```

Original answer... misunderstood the question a bit but it has a helpful link:

This is the default behavior for rails, it is not backwards.

You're nested route basically reads, "Each resource mom has a set of sub/nested resources named kids".

This page is a great resource.. I've linked to the nested routes section so maybe it can help clear this issue up for you. [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: I'm not saying the objects are the wrong way round. /moms/n/kids/m is correct. I'm saying the ids are the wrong way round: the mom's id in the database is 1, the kid's is 2 but the path is /moms/2/kids/1. I've clarified this in the question - thanks for your input.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. I believe you have to pass both the mom and the kid into that method. Can you try mom_kid_path(mom,kid)  ? instead of just passing in kid?

Comment: Msencenb, you are the man. In fact I needed mom_kid_path(kid.mom, kid) because there was no mom variable available - if you add an answer to this effect I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad its fixed! I've edited the answer above to reflect how you fixed it :)